# How to obtain a closeness score bounded between 0 and 1

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to calculate the closeness of a network like e.g.

```
relations=structure(list(From = c("France", "Italy", "Malta", "Spain", 
"Germany", "Austria", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", 
"Greece", "Slovakia", "Belgium", "Luxembourg", "Estonia", "Germany", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Cyprus", "Greece", "Lithuania", 
"Estonia", "Greece", "Lithuania", "Slovakia", "Netherlands", 
"Luxembourg", "Estonia", "Malta", "Belgium", "Cyprus", "Austria", 
"Estonia", "Austria", "Germany", "Austria", "Netherlands", "Portugal", 
"Portugal", "Estonia", "Italy", "Spain", "Finland", "Belgium", 
"Spain", "Estonia", "Latvia", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", 
"Italy", "Lithuania", "Cyprus", "Ireland", "Luxembourg", "Ireland", 
"Spain", "Belgium", "Latvia", "Netherlands", "Italy", "Slovenia", 
"Netherlands", "Greece", "Spain", "Austria", "Finland", "Malta", 
"Spain", "Austria", "Lithuania", "France", "Portugal", "Cyprus", 
"Finland", "Spain", "Spain", "Belgium", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Greece", "Netherlands", "Luxembourg", "Estonia", "Ireland", 
"Italy", "Portugal", "Greece", "Estonia", "Belgium", "Germany", 
"Slovenia", "Slovakia", "Lithuania", "Slovenia", "Portugal", 
"Portugal", "Slovakia", "France", "Portugal", "Netherlands"), 
    To = c("Slovakia", "Germany", "Portugal", "Austria", "Latvia", 
    "Cyprus", "Portugal", "Greece", "Italy", "Slovenia", "Ireland", 
    "Malta", "Ireland", "Germany", "Cyprus", "Portugal", "Slovenia", 
    "Italy", "Luxembourg", "France", "Slovakia", "Netherlands", 
    "Greece", "France", "Ireland", "Netherlands", "Cyprus", "Germany", 
    "Portugal", "Austria", "Luxembourg", "Austria", "Spain", 
    "Netherlands", "Belgium", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Luxembourg", 
    "Finland", "Belgium", "Lithuania", "Austria", "Spain", "Slovenia", 
    "Luxembourg", "Finland", "Slovenia", "Germany", "Austria", 
    "Slovenia", "Slovenia", "Portugal", "Finland", "Lithuania", 
    "Latvia", "France", "Netherlands", "Cyprus", "Spain", "Malta", 
    "France", "Finland", "Belgium", "Latvia", "Slovenia", "Slovenia", 
    "Cyprus", "Slovakia", "Slovakia", "Latvia", "Austria", "Ireland", 
    "Luxembourg", "Belgium", "Italy", "Estonia", "Greece", "Slovakia", 
    "Belgium", "Italy", "Latvia", "Malta", "Greece", "France", 
    "Greece", "Netherlands", "France", "Slovenia", "Latvia", 
    "Finland", "Austria", "Slovenia", "Belgium", "Cyprus", "Greece", 
    "Slovenia", "Cyprus", "Finland", "Malta", "Germany"), weight = c(3.63689639539779e-09, 
    2.36155345798604e-11, 1.90981717262912e-08, 1.27550515412245e-09, 
    2.75032212941667e-09, 3.79663088493923e-08, 1.42368280746262e-08, 
    1.51146811601353e-08, 1.75314892144034e-09, 2.07956027448449e-08, 
    1.38623943876156e-07, 1.92893849444567e-08, 5.66419694274739e-08, 
    5.8089561312222e-09, 1.95827364947702e-09, 6.7071674411728e-10, 
    4.23667746162198e-09, 4.62966220873406e-08, 1.21403390886489e-07, 
    1.26979107479853e-08, 5.59978765605208e-07, 3.14788992090851e-09, 
    5.0058794053616e-07, 5.22186410794211e-09, 9.21607337940845e-10, 
    2.51322812227745e-09, 3.04984607426863e-07, 3.20992561385791e-09, 
    8.92180336424503e-10, 6.12766236972513e-08, 1.20231538847898e-08, 
    1.34589665048046e-07, 8.84238627642763e-10, 2.63370671763944e-11, 
    1.11903749128791e-09, 1.16731679208085e-08, 4.99654438989995e-08, 
    2.90162442064053e-08, 2.55621731534268e-09, 1.58298464637584e-10, 
    5.07475932446428e-08, 2.54927518867625e-09, 2.24427326793633e-10, 
    4.49723284363684e-09, 2.43010060636845e-06, 1.90760030501003e-08, 
    6.35902610582491e-08, 5.48833215255332e-10, 4.06612010446768e-10, 
    5.32889353797193e-10, 1.23745070305762e-06, 8.89608483306497e-07, 
    3.75876719292064e-09, 4.44758324449273e-07, 1.35536579831994e-07, 
    5.42265922046125e-11, 4.8233448207134e-11, 3.4286615533894e-07, 
    2.0214285544428e-10, 8.57988303618593e-10, 1.35631258148319e-09, 
    7.97944858545598e-10, 4.2673026648725e-09, 9.28491399244895e-08, 
    1.03420112425729e-09, 2.4972909387896e-08, 8.12118760999133e-07, 
    1.31225365800221e-08, 1.77287287047586e-09, 6.53958727055997e-09, 
    3.05841917976996e-10, 9.20687775127977e-09, 4.32323785012335e-07, 
    8.40653865200987e-10, 1.23500809608508e-10, 6.59008808575339e-08, 
    1.13962199159936e-09, 4.68300414991578e-10, 3.54758342726504e-11, 
    6.55880483863129e-10, 1.17833628272869e-08, 5.08802989644665e-07, 
    7.22191649442396e-07, 2.7028184600344e-10, 2.2810918951755e-10, 
    8.10987753872438e-10, 1.50406384816011e-09, 5.46176491471454e-06, 
    2.32716789835402e-08, 2.10873259303399e-10, 1.81735402994258e-09, 
    9.71369590422109e-09, 2.01941765282435e-08, 1.8961914804496e-07, 
    9.4461402995167e-09, 1.69816623519093e-07, 9.16774899583353e-08, 
    8.54588845128718e-10, 4.79160495478785e-08, 2.31994460360924e-11
    )), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
actors= c("Slovakia", "Germany", "Portugal", "Austria", "Latvia", "Cyprus", 
"Greece", "Italy", "Slovenia", "Ireland", "Malta", "Luxembourg", 
"France", "Netherlands", "Spain", "Belgium", "Finland", "Lithuania", 
"Estonia")
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
```

by using package `igraph`. Using function `closeness` I obtain:

```
closeness(g)
   Slovakia     Germany    Portugal     Austria      Latvia      Cyprus      Greece       Italy    Slovenia     Ireland 
    4002492     7111002     6478738     6502665     2017834     1029940     6615891     7164685     5533119     6240785 
      Malta  Luxembourg      France Netherlands       Spain     Belgium     Finland   Lithuania     Estonia 
    5071100     7243749     6342911     7121291     7144000     7090895     6415382     3086085     7411727
```

I would like to obtain a normalized closeness score bounded between 0 and 1. It is 0 if a node is an isolate, and 1 if a node is directly connected all others. What can I do

Comment: You say you want a score that is 1 for any vertex that is connected to all others, but you are working with weighted graphs. The closeness value depends not only on which vertex is connected to which, but also the edge weights. Weighted closeness simply does not work the way you want it to. You also say that you want 0 for isolated vertices, but closeness simply does not make sense for disconnected graphs. Perhaps you are looking for something else than closeness. I would suggest thinking about this and trying to come up with a mathematically precise way to formulate the question.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thank you very much. I understand now, my request is not well posed from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: Could you provide a definition of your "closeness" (seems not the conventional one) and show how it can be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried normalizing it yourself out of `igraph`? You might use `caret` package:

```
library(caret)
c1 <-closeness(g)
df <- tibble(actors = actors,
             close = c1)
df_normalized <- df %>% 
  preProcess(., method=c("range")) %>% 
  predict(., df)

df_normalized
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function, you can call for "normalized = TRUE" because it is "FALSE" by default. Sidenote: It is helpful if you add the code you used to calculate closeness.

```
closeness(
  graph,
  vids = V(graph),
  mode = c("out", "in", "all", "total"),
  weights = NULL,
  normalized = TRUE
)
```

Comment: This does not do what OP is asking for. `normalized=T` computes the inverse mean distance to all other nodes. `normalized=F` computes the inverse sum of distances to all other nodes.